# UI Router ui-sref or $state.go not changing state AT ALL... NO ERROR

Tags: angularjs

**UPDATE:**

Note the below issue is still the problem, however @SurilD hint allowed me to see the actual error I am getting (why this is hidden by default I have no idea!). I am now getting "**Unknown provider: SearchControllerProvider <- SearchController**" error and I think it's to do with the way i'm attaching the controllers to the UI Routers routes. I am not passing in the controller as a dependancy anywhere so I can only think that the below is causing it...

```
$stateProvider
            .state('start', {
                url: '/start',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: "/Navbar/show",
                        controller: "SearchController",
                        resolve: { SearchController: "SearchController" }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: "/Search/dashboard",
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    }
                }
            })
```

**ORIGINAL POST /**

I had this working before converting my controllers to IIFE's and now i have sorted all that, when I go to the page it WILL NOT update anything when you click on a ui-sref link, or click a button which calls a method on the controller to do some stuff and then do $state.go. I am using HTML5 mode (no hashtags).

Here is my relevant **markup**:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li id="searchboxmenu" class="searchboxmenu">
                <a ui-sref="showresults({ searchcriteia: ''})">
                    <span class="menuicon fa-stack fa-fw pull-left"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x fa-stack-1x "></i></span><span class="menutext">
                        <div ng-app="OdinSPA" ng-controller="SearchController" class="searchbox input-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="inputcapture" class="input-group form-control restricted" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button ng-click="search()" class="btn input-group" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2w"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="start"><span class="menuicon fa-stack fa-fw pull-left"><i class="fa fa-tags fa-3x fa-stack-1x "></i></span><span class="menutext">Orders</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="guru"><span class="menuicon fa-stack fa-fw pull-left"><i class="fa fa-database fa-magic fa-3x fa-stack-1x "></i></span><span class="menutext">Guru</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="reports"><span class="menuicon fa-stack fa-fw pull-left"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-3x fa-stack-1x "></i></span><span class="menutext">Reports</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="#"><span class="menuicon fa-stack fa-fw pull-left"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x fa-stack-1x "></i></span><span class="menutext">New</span> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And then my **statehelper.js** is...

```
(function () {
  angular.module('OdinSPA')
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
        $stateProvider
            .state('start', {
                url: '/start',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: '/Navbar/show',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: '/Search/dashboard',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('showresults', {
                url: '/Search/ListResults?searchCriteria',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: function (params) { return '/Search/ListResults?searchCriteria=' + params.searchCriteria; },
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: function (params) { return '/Search/dashboard' },
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: {
                            SearchController: 'SearchController',
                            oneThing: function ($stateParams) {
                                console.log($stateParams); // comes through fine
                                var state = this;
                                console.log(state); // will give you a "raw" state object
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('guru', {
                url: '/guru',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: '/Navbar/show',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: 'Search/reportEdit',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('report', {
                url: '/guru',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: '/Navbar/show',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: '/Search/dashboard',
                        controller: 'SearchController',
                        resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('loginRegister', {
                url: '/loginRegister?returnUrl',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
                        controller: 'LoginController',
                        resolve: { LoginController: 'LoginController' }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: '/Account/Register',
                        controller: 'RegisterController',
                        resolve: { RegisterController: 'RegisterController' }
                    }
                }
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/home', 'start');
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('start');

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthHttpResponseInterceptor');

    }]);
})();
```

My Controller code is getting hit as I get the **$window.alert** happening

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('OdinSPA')
    .controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$state', '$window', 'SearchService',
        function ($scope, $state, $window, SearchService) {
            $scope.searchResults = function () {
                return "bollocjs";//SearchService.searchResults();
            }
            $scope.search = function () {
                var param = {};
                $window.alert($scope.inputcapture);
                param.searchCriteria = $scope.inputcapture;
                $state.go('showresults', { searchCriteria: param.searchCriteria });
            }
            $scope.showsearch = false;
        }
    ])
})();
```

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Comment: UI-Router doesn't throw errors, so if there is a problem you won't notice it. You should consider adding an event handler for `$stateChangeError`, as discussed on the bottom of this [UI-Router wiki page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Comment: if I change the state to one that doesn't exist then it errors.... therefore it is obviously finding the state.... but thanks... will take a look at that article @Suril D

Comment: The errors I'm referring to are not just because it can't find the state, but more general errors that cause exceptions like trying to access a property on an object that is undefined.

Comment: @Suril D! Great that helped me see what was going on... will edit the question to see if you can shed any more light on what the route issue is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has similar issues, it was indeed the way I was attaching the controllers to the route. I don't know which article recommended using the resolve: for the controller, but it don't need it if your controllers are written in a standard way, it resolves the string name anyway. Therefore the state helper now looks like

```
            $stateProvider
            .state('start', {
                url: '/start',
                views: {
                    "navBar": {
                        templateUrl: "/Navbar/show",
                        controller: "SearchController",
          //              resolve: { SearchController: "SearchController" }
                    },
                    "mainDiv": {
                        templateUrl: "/Search/dashboard",
                        controller: 'SearchController',
           //             resolve: { SearchController: 'SearchController' }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Which works perfectly...

If anyone is searching for a problem where you aren't getting any errors on changing state but it's not working, follow @Suril D's link and add the error handling, makes life so much easier!!

Thanks for all the help guys, as always!

Comment: The `$stateChangeError` event is deprecated. Error hooks can now be registered using `$transitions.onError` (https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onerror)